# looking for log4j vulnerability fix

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I have upgraded log4j to 2.17.2 to fix vulnerabilities reported by blackduck scan. Most of them gone except one. It is because of log4j.dtd file present in folder log4j-1.2-api-2.17.2\org\apache\log4j\xml.
I am not sure how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: Same is with 2.20.0

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check or post a query or bug on github forum of log4j? asking if it really is a vulnerability or blackduck identifies as one

Comment: @Harsh I will post there as well. Thanks!